# freenect_launch with Kinect

Tags: ros, freenect-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i follow this answer:http://answers.ros.org/question/196455/kinect-installation-and-setup-on-ros-updated/
I understand Openni_launch does not work anymore under Indigo for Kinect
so I install freenect_launch already
it seems to connect the Kinect but not work correctly
[ INFO] [1429730425.213607711]: Starting a 3s RGB and Depth stream flush.
[ INFO] [1429730425.221435448]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 0:0 with serial number 'A70773X01270231A'
[ WARN] [1429730425.381519441]: Could not find any compatible depth output mode for 1. Falling back to default depth output mode 1.
[ INFO] [1429730425.444282494]: rgb_frame_id = 'camera_rgb_optical_frame'
[ INFO] [1429730425.444783170]: depth_frame_id = 'camera_depth_optical_frame'
[ WARN] [1429730425.552470857]: Camera calibration file /home/sony/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A70773X01270231A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1429730425.560671122]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1429730425.572181403]: Camera calibration file /home/sony/.ros/camera_info/depth_A70773X01270231A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1429730425.576274468]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
process[camera_base_link1-20]: started with pid [11928]
process[camera_base_link2-21]: started with pid [11973]
[ INFO] [1429730428.225654320]: Stopping device RGB and Depth stream flush.

thank you for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207642/freenect_launch-with-kinect/) by [sony](https://answers.ros.org/users/22164/sony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-04-22**:
Can you give more information about "but not work correctly" ?
 What doesnt work ?
 Do you receive images?
Be aware that by default freenect_launch does not enable depth_registration, you can emable it either by modifying the launchfile or using the GUI rqt_reconfigure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Openni provides a driver that works.
**this is an out of the box solution!**
just type in your console

```
Sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-camera
Sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-launch
```

then u have to change something at the driver:
download this driver:https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/zipball/unstable

and input the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip avin2-SensorKinect-v0.93-5.1.2.1-0-g15f1975.zip 
cd avin2-SensorKinect-15f1975/Bin
tar -xjf SensorKinect093-Bin-Linux-x64-v5.1.2.1.tar.bz2
cd Sensor-Bin-Linux-x64-v5.1.2.1
sudo ./install.sh
```

after that it will work, for a **live test of kinect** open rviz and add a topic or type in:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

open a new terminal and type in:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

---

Originally posted by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) with karma: 201 on 2015-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sony](https://answers.ros.org/users/22164/sony/) on 2015-06-07**:
Dear felixwatzlawik,
thank you so much that I installed openni successfully
but I ran the command roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
it shows
[openni.launch] is neither a launch file in package [openni_launch] nor is [openni_launch] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written

**Comment by [sony](https://answers.ros.org/users/22164/sony/) on 2015-06-07**:
to the log file.
if i intalled worng position?

**Comment by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on 2015-06-08**:
something must have gone wrong with your installation, the line with roslaunch works for me..

**Comment by [sony](https://answers.ros.org/users/22164/sony/) on 2015-06-08**:
I`ll try again. thank you so much^^